# SwiftUI: Border is double in size at the rounded edges of button

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, overlay

I get a double border on a button and it looks strange. I tried to create the shape with RoundRectangle overlay, and got the same result. This is the code I use:

```
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack {
            Button(action:{ action()}) {
                   Label("Name", image: "info")
               }
            .frame(height: 40)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .background(.clear)
            .overlay(
                Capsule(style: .continuous)
                .stroke(.green, lineWidth: 1)
            )}}
```

And the result is:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that the border is double thickness at the sides, it's that it's half thickness at the top and bottom. The button is being clipped by the `ScrollView`.

In this case you can fix it by adding a padding to your `HStack`:

**Before:**

[image]

**Adding `.padding([.top, .bottom], 1)` to `HStack`**:

[image]

Comment: I did not even considered this! Thx.